# Function is monotonically decreasing from finite value to zero. When is it's integral finite?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have a "nice" (i.e. $C^{\infty}$, see pic for qualitative behaviour) function $f(r)$ , that is monotonically decreasing from a finite value at $r =0$ to zero at $r = \infty$ . Under what conditions can I conclude that
$$ \int_0^\infty f(r) dr < \infty$$
?

For what it's worth I've attached a few variations of it below, the explicit analytic form of it is rather cumbersome.
[image: The function in question]

Comment: Well, you always have the integral test…

Comment: Well, it really depends on the explicit form.

Comment: If you can find $N$ such that $x>N \implies f(x)<\frac 1x$ you will have proved convergence

Comment: @WW1 $1/(x+1)$ is a counterexample

Comment: The blue curve is not monotonically decreasing. You seem to have a set of functions that depends on the parameter $\alpha$. If you [edit] the question to tell us the actual (ugly) function and ask for a cutoff value for the parameter we might be able to help. As asked, the question is much too general.

Comment: @AndrewZhang  I stand corrected. If you can find $b<-1$ such that $x>N \implies f(x)<x^b$, that should do it

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, bit sloppy figure on my part. Nevertheless, a lower bound can be easily constructed that *is* montonically decreasing, and I managed to show non-convergence of the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can show that :

$$f(x) =_\infty O(x^{-a}), a>1$$

You will have the convergence of the improper integral.

Comment: This is pretty much what I figured. Unfortunately in my case this can't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use here Cauchy- Integral Test for convergence. The test says if f is Monotonically decreasing positive function on $[0, \infty) $ then
$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges if & only if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ f(n) converges.

Here, if Your function is postive on $[0, \infty)$ & the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges then given integral converges.

Comment: Thanks, the numerical evaluation of this series up to a cut-off $n_{Max}$ is fairly easy, and the non-convergence in the $n_{Max}$ variable can be read off quickly!